# How to open .mobi with double click

Tags: 11.10, mobi

I have .mobi book and want double click on it to open book with Calibre eReader. I tried to open choosing option Open with other application but there is not Calibre eReader.
Of course everything is ok, when I first open Calibre and then choose book.

How to set file association for .mobi?

Answer (score 1):

Install fbreader 
right click on the .mobi file and chose open with entry

then chose fbreader from it

you can access .mobi file next time onwards by double clicking it

or
use ubuntu-tweak to associate extensions with applications

Answer (score 1):

Install FB Reader.

Right click on it and choose to open with E-Book Reader (FB Reader).

Next time when you click on it, it will open with it by default.

Complete instructions: http://itsfoss.com/how-to-read-mobi-files-ubuntu/